# Study the convergence of the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{x-n}{x^2}\cdot\chi_{(n,+\infty)}(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, sequence-of-function

For every $n\in\mathbb{N^+}$, let $f_n:(0,+\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be as defined:
$$f_n(x)=\frac{x-n}{x^2}\cdot\chi_{(n,+\infty)}(x).$$

Study the convergence of the sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N^+}}$ in $L^p((0,+\infty))$.

The pointwise limit I think is $0$ because the indicator function on a smaller and smaller interval going to infinity.

Moreover, since $f_n(x)<0$ when $x<n$ so in this interval the indicator function is $0$, so the $L^1$ norm that is
$$\int_n^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x}-\frac{n}{x^2}dx=(\frac{n}{x}+\mathrm{log}(x)|_n^{+\infty}=+\infty$$

Since the $L^1$ norm is not finite, can we conclude that the sequence does not converge weakly (and so strongly) in $L^1$?

Moreover, can we say that the $L^p$ norms are also infinite?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: I would guess that the $L^p$ norms for p>1 are finite. The integral of 1/x (which is essentially what you dealt with for the p=1 case) is right on the borderline of convergence. If you raise to the p power then it will converge.

Comment: The sequence is not contained in $L^1$, so it cannot converge in $L^1$ (what you mean by strongly I guess, I don't now about strongly vs. weakly - anyway, just by the naming, if it's not converging strongly, it still may be converging weakly). Using a very simple bound it can easily be shown that the other $L^p$-norms are finite.

Comment: One has $f_n(x)\leq x^{-1} \chi_{(n,\infty)}(x)$ and you can easily compute the $L^p$-norm of the right-hand side.

Comment: @MaoWao is it not a problem the fact that $(f_n(x))^p$ for $p$ even can be greater than $(1/x)^p$ ?

Comment: @sound wave, $f_n$ is positive and the $p$-th power is increasing on the positive reals, so $f_n(x)^p\leq x^{-1/p}\chi_{(n,\infty)}(x)$.

Comment: @MaoWao why you say $f_n$ is positive? Fix $x=1$ and take $n=4$, then $f_4(1)=-3$, while $1/x=1$, taking a positive power, eg $p=2$ we get $(f_4(1))^2=9>(1/x)^2=1$. Ah but $\chi_{(4,\infty)}(1)=0$ so actually $f_4(1)=0$. So you are saying that $f_n$ is positive because it never takes negative values?

Comment: @MaoWao You're saying $f_n(x)\le x^{-1}\chi_{(n,\infty)}(x)$ and $f_n(x)^p\le x^{-1/p}\chi_{(n,\infty)}(x)$ at the same time, but $[x^{-1}]^p\ne x^{-1/p}$

Comment: @jameswatt, you're absolutely right, it should be $x^{-p}$ instead of $x^{-1/p}$ (which is better, as the latter would not be integrable)

Comment: @soundwave, of course you have to take the indicator function into account. And of course being positive and not taking strictly negative values is the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that $f_n(x)\leq x^{-1}\chi_{(n,\infty)}(x)$, so we don't have to take powers of the sum in the numerator.

If $x\leq n$, then $f_n(x)=0$ because of the indicator function. If $x>n$, then $x-n>0$ and thus $f_n(x)>0$. In any case, $f_n(x)\geq 0$. Hence $f_n(x)^p\leq x^{-p}\chi_{(n,\infty)}(x)$.

Now you can either compute $\int_n^\infty x^{-p}\,dx$ and see that it converges to zero, or, if you are as lazy as me and already know that $x^{-p}$ is integrable at $\infty$, you can just evoke the dominated convergence theorem (clearly $x^{-p}\chi_{(n,\infty)}(x)\to 0$ pointwise and $x^{-p}\chi_{(n,\infty)}(x)\leq x^{-p}\chi_{(1,\infty)}(x)$).